# Specific password regular expression

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am having problems creating a regular expresion. It needs to fullfill the following:

1) Has 8-12 characters

2) At least 1 uppercase letter

3) At least 3 lowercase letters

4) At least 1 number

5) At least 1 special character

6) Has to start with a lowercase, upercase or numeric

7) Maximum of 2 repeating characters

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.*` will technically work. I will not show more effort until you do.

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at matching "must contain at least _N_ of ..."  Why can't you just write a subroutine that scans the string one time and counts how many characters are seen that fit each of the required categories?

Comment: `Maximum of 2 repeating characters` - What does this mean ?

Comment: Maximum of 2 repeating characters :
For example, 'password' is acceptable, 'passsword' isnt

Comment: For future reference, @IlijaStevanović , please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~])(?=(?:(.)(?!\1\1))+$)[a-zA-Z0-9].{7,11}$
```

Explained / Expanded

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?= .* [A-Z] )                # 1 upper
 (?=
      (?: .* [a-z] ){3}             # 3 lower
 )
 (?= .* [0-9] )                # 1 number
 (?=
      .* [!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]   # 1 special
 )
 (?=                           # Maximum 2 repeating
      (?:
           ( . )                         # (1)
           (?! \1 \1 )
      )+
      $ 
 )
 [a-zA-Z0-9]                   # First alnum
 .{7,11}                       # 8 to 12 max chars
 $                             # EOS
```

Answer (score 0):

What you got so far?
Also, which set of regex are you using ?

I'd start with the length of the expression

1. Restrict it to be 8-12, something like [a-zA-Z]{8,12}
2. For the requirements on the first one you can use a []+

For the other requirements it's a little tricker

Comment: For now: minimum eight and maximum 12 characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character:
"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,12}"